# Showing that if the conditional probabilities exist.

Tags: probability

I'm trying to show that

If the conditional probabilities exist, then
 P(A1 $\cap$ A2 $\cap$ ... $\cap$An) = P(A1)P(A2|A1)...P(An|A1$\cap$A2$\cap$...$\cap$An-1).

I'm unsure how to approach these sorts of problems as I'm still fairly new to Probability.

I started off with saying:

Let A1, A2, ..., An be events, each with P(Ai) >= 0 for all i $\in$ {1, 2, 3, ...}.

We have by our hypothesis that the conditional probabilities exist, so by definition we have that:

P(A2|A1) = $\frac{P(A2 \cap A1)}{P(A1)}$

...

P(An|An-1) = $\frac{P(An \cap An-1)}{P(An-1)}$

Then by the multiplication law:

P(An-1 $\cap$ An) = P(An|An-1)P(An-1)

(and so on).

So

P(A1 $\cap$ A2 $\cap$ ... $\cap$An) = P(A1 $\cap$ A2) P(A3 $\cap$ A4) ... P(An-1$\cap$An)

Before I even go on, is what I did here correct so far? The above line strikes me as not convincing as I'm not sure if there is such a property to allow me to do what I did above. The idea I had was to substitute an n number of conditional probability equations (in the form of the multiplicative law) and then multiply them all together.

But generally speaking I am not sure if I understand how to approach these sorts of problems - so any help appreciated.

Do note that this is elementary probability so I only have a limited tool set I can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

note that the k'th term is
$$P(A_k| A_1\cap A_2\cap ...\cap A_{k-1} ) = \frac{P( A_1\cap A_2\cap ...\cap A_{k-1}\cap A_k )}{ P(A_1\cap A_2\cap ...\cap A_{k-1} )}$$
from which you obtain a telescopic product

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm able to do with a telescopic product. :x EDIT: Oh, I see what you mean... Then the numerator can be further broken down by conditional probability law to obtain the correct equation?

Comment: It is like : $(a/b) \times (b/c) \times (c/d) \times...$. Try to write your expression down in your case. You may start with the case $n=3$ after which the result should become obvious (hopefully).

Comment: I can see that everything should cancel out except a / d but I don't know how to justify that the intersections of the probability can be rewritten as products. Is doing P(A1) * P(A2) * P(A3) * ... * P(Ak-1) * P(Ak) a valid claim? If so, why? Otherwise, I am not quite sure I see how I can expand this out to be telescopic.

EDIT: I do see P(A and B) = P(A) * P(B) But I thought that's what we were trying to prove here (at least in the case of the numerator. :x)

Comment: Got it... I expanded out the denom and multiplied to the left. Heh.